# Issues loading data from a struct into a vector of that struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

The structure is only in one function of my class. I have been debugging and trying everything I can think of. This is for a graph and the function is for a Dijkstra formula. The main issue I get is that my data never gets into my vector (vector open).

Not sure if all the code is need since all the problems happen in this function. Code not currently used (trying to get data into the vector first) has been commented out.

```
void Graph::Dijkstra(string start, string end, vector<string> &path)
{
    struct node
    {
        string name;
        vector<string> connection;
        int costSoFar;

        node() {name = " "; costSoFar = 0;}

        node(node& other)
        {
            name = other.name;
            connection = other.connection;
            costSoFar = other.costSoFar;
        }
    };

    vector<string> adjacent;
    node startNode;
    node current;
    node endNode;
    vector<node> open;
    node closed[MAX_VERTICES];
    int small, temp;
    bool found = false;
    bool inClosed = false;
    bool inOpen = false;
    string tempVertex;

    // starting node is added open list
    // startNode = node();
    startNode.name = start;
    startNode.costSoFar = 0;

    //adjacent.push_back(startNode.name);
    open.push_back(startNode);

    temp = 0; // used a place holder for debugging
    //open[0].name = startNode.name; 
    //open[0].costSoFar = startNode.costSoFar;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have looked at similar post and attempted their suggestions not sure why my vector will not take input even if I try to directly apply it (see commented code above).

Comment: Unrelated: `startNode = node();` is useless. its already a constructed `node`.

Comment: What data are you not seeing in the vector? You do realize that your vector open is local and will be deallocated immediately after you exit the function right?

Comment: Before C++11 it wasn't legal to have a vector of a struct which is locally defined within a function. Try moving `struct node` to file scope and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: To get better help you'll need to post a test-case. Also "vector cannot take input" isn't a thing, please say what you expect to happen and what actually happened. The code you've shown puts an object in a vector and then doesn't attempt to generate output or do anything else afterwards.

Comment: @WhozCraig - the line is left over from a previous version.

Comment: @o_weisman yes it does not need to keep the data after the function is complete.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The issue is that the elements (data) of the node structure are not added to the vector open. When debugging I can view their values and startNode is fine but when pushing it into the vector all the vector shows is ?? and the program eventual fails

Comment: How do you know they're not added to the vector and what is "the vector shows is ??" ? Add some code that outputs from the vector.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I do not need to.. The debugger shows me the real time value of each variable I check, as I move through the code. No need to do extra code if not needed.

Comment: Perhaps your debugger is giving you false information here. Maybe it can't cope with having a vector of objects with locally-defined type.

Answer (score 0):

I believe std containers require a copy constructor of the form:

```
node(const node& other);
```

That's the form of the default copy constructor if you don't provide one. If do provide a copy constructor then this default one will not be provided for you, so you must define one of that form.

Comment: He did provide a copy-constructor. However, if he didn't, then the compiler would generate one and it would be correct.

Comment: Yes, my answer may not have been clear, but what I mean is that he needs a copy constructor of that form and he doesn't have one. Changing `node(node& other)` to `node(const node& other)` might work.

Comment: @Nathan I have attempted that format as well but it does not fix the problem of the data from my node never getting into the vector open

Answer (score 0):

OK I found my own solution. It appears if the structure is created inside the function it cannot access variables the way it needs to. All I did was move the node struct to the outside of the function.

```
struct node
{
    string name;
    vector<string> connection;
    int costSoFar;

    node() {name = " "; costSoFar = 0;}

    node(const node& other)
    {
        name = other.name;
        connection = other.connection;
        costSoFar = other.costSoFar;
    }
};

void Graph::Dijkstra(string start, string end, vector<string> &path)
{ // the other code needed }
```

Comment: That's exactly what Matt McNabb told you to do isn't it?

Comment: Sorry just seen that post by him must have missed it the first time.